# How can i extract multiple fields from a nushell record using a wildcard?

Tags: nushell

I am trying to process a package.json file.

```
open package.json | get scripts
```

This gives all the entries under scripts property as a nushell record.

```
╭──────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ postbuild        │ scripts/post-build.sh                                                                │
│ ng               │ ng                                                                                   │
│ start            │ npm run prebuild && ng serve                                                         │
│ start:local      │ ng serve -c local                                                                    │
│ prebuild         │ rm -rf dist && rm -rf dist.zip && ts-node -O '{"module": "commonjs"}' git.version.ts │
│ prebuild2        │ ts-node -O '{"module": "commonjs"}' git.version.ts                                   │
│ build            │ ng build                                                                             │
│ build:vnv3api    │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c vnv3api && npm run postbuild                         │
│ build:vnv2web    │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c vnv2web && npm run postbuild                         │
│ build:vnv3web    │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c vnv3web && npm run postbuild                         │
│ build:vnv1web    │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c vnv1web && npm run postbuild                         │
│ build:stageweb   │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c stageweb --stats-json && npm run postbuild           │
│ build:prodbeta   │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c prodbeta && npm run postbuild                        │
│ build:production │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c production && npm run postbuild                      │
│ build:local      │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c local && npm run postbuild                           │
│ test             │ ng test                                                                              │
│ lint             │ tslint -p .                                                                          │
│ lint_and_fix     │ tslint -p . --fix                                                                    │
│ e2e              │ CHROME_MODE=headless ng e2e --dev-server-target=                                     │
│ e2e:debug        │ ng e2e --dev-server-target=                                                          │
╰──────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

I want to filter the keys/rows which start with build
I want to perform something like;

```
open package.json | get scripts | select build*
```

Expected output:

```
                                                                                                              
╭──────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮                                │
│ build            │ ng build                                                                             │
│ build:vnv3api    │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c vnv3api && npm run postbuild                         │
│ build:vnv2web    │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c vnv2web && npm run postbuild                         │
│ build:vnv3web    │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c vnv3web && npm run postbuild                         │
│ build:vnv1web    │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c vnv1web && npm run postbuild                         │
│ build:stageweb   │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c stageweb --stats-json && npm run postbuild           │
│ build:prodbeta   │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c prodbeta && npm run postbuild                        │
│ build:production │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c production && npm run postbuild                      │
│ build:local      │ npm run prebuild && ng build -c local && npm run postbuild                           │                                                       │
╰──────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example you provided, you can `transpose` the record to a table, select the rows matching the desired pattern, and (if needed) `transpose` it back to a record:

```
open package.json
| get scripts
| transpose key value
| where key =~ '^build'
| transpose -dr
```

- `transpose key value` converts the record to a table with the columns named `key` and `value`
- The `where` clause with `=~` is a regex pattern selecting any `key` that starts with "build"
- `transpose -dr` converts it back to a record.

There might be some other patterns that work here, but I believe they are probably all going to involve a `transpose` at some point, so this may be the most expediate.